# Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed for rgbdslam_v2

Tags: ros, eigen, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

When I run catkin_make for rgbdslam_v2 in ROS Indigo. I get the error below. This is only part of the error, couldn't get the rest.

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/4cedfe80c1c3197b27f896c56bd404b9

Here are the [CMakeLists.txt](http://pastebin.com/gxXXaWbL) and [package.xml](http://pastebin.com/0HmZJ0M9) files.

My pc also freezes sometimes when running catkin_make for this package.

Thank you

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250318/invoking-%22make--j8--l8%22-failed-for-rgbdslam_v2/) by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no error in your snippet which means we don't know why it crashed. But if your computer is freezing occasionally while compiling you're likely running out of memory. You should compile with less parallelism. (lower -j number)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1